# Can we use http request in beanshell?

Tags: while-loop, jmeter, beanshell

Can we use http request in beanshell?

**Explanation:** Lets say, I have a http request as HTTPREQUEST1. When I request HTTPREQUEST1 then I will get some response lets say "response1" which is not my expected response.

Do we have any mechanism in beanshell, from where I can request HTTPREQUEST1 using  while loop until I get my expected response?

```
while(response != "expected response")
{
    HTTPREQUEST1;
}
```

I know it can be accomplished by extracting regular expression and while controller. I want it from beanshell. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be using [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) for this, however if for some reason you have to do it via Beanshell - here you go.

Add [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) or [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) as a child of the sampler, you want to execute and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
while(!SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString().equals("expected response")) {
    ctx.getCurrentSampler().sample(null);   
}
```

For the Beanshell Listener you should be using `sampleResult` (starts with lowercase `s`)

See the following reference material:

- JavaDoc on [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) and [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) classes
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Comment: I tried but my script freezes. Will you please elaborate this code?

Comment: Moreover, I get following error hc.parameters httpclient parameters does not exist.